# How to get PreviousAll element Child class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get previous all element class list using jquery.

Here is the Example.

```
<div>
   <div>
     <span class="one">one</span>
   </div>

   <div>
     <span class="two">one</span>
   </div>

   <div>
     <span class="three">one</span>
   </div>

   <div id="getclass">getclass</div>          

   <div>
     <span class="four">one</span>
   </div> 

</div>
```

I want all the class names above in "**getclass**" id.

And i'm trying the below things.

```
  var a = $("#getclass").prevAll().find('.class').attr('class');
```

How can i achive this using jquery.Anyone please Help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is looking for elements with the class *class*.

You can instead get all [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) of [previous siblings](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and then use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to convert this to an array with just class names by returning the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property.

Example:

```js
var a = $("#getclass")
  .prevAll()
  .children("span")
  .get()
  .map(function(x) {
    return x.className;
  });

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <span class="one">one</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="two">one</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="three">one</span>
  </div>

  <div id="getclass">getclass</div>

  <div>
    <span class="four">one</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read each element through a loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         var classes = [];
         $("#getclass").prevAll().each(function () {
             classes.push($(this).find('span').attr('class'));
         });

         var classNames = classes.join(",");
         alert(classNames);
     });
```

**classes** is an array of class names, you can also get it as a CSV.

Comment: Hope this may help others